# How to keep my hover css active after hover? Using routerlink

Tags: html, css, hover

Working with Angular 4 and bootstrap.  Have a Navbar that creates a line before and makes it visible on hover. I am having a hard time making the hover styling stay when it is active. Not sure how the :before is affecting it.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:before{
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-color: #fff;
 visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
 transform: scaleX(0);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover:before{
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Current Active styling that activates using this in nav: `[routerLinkActive]="['active']"`

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a {
  font-size: 17px;
  background-color: #0B9788 !important;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Comment: `.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover:before,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a.active:before` ---> you simply change the `:hover` with `.active` class

Comment: Yes, I've tried changing it to active but nothing seems to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript code in that situation. You can use the following code:

```
document.getElementById('some-id').onmouseover = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#0B9788"
}
```

You can see this code in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/tk7p2br5/2/

Comment: I am not having an issue with the hover. I am having an issue keeping the hover styling active. In Angular, I am using `[routerLinkActive]="['active']"` to activate the active CSS styling.

Comment: Try this.. as soon as the mouse pointer comes over the element.. then the given styling will get activated forever

Comment: I didn't downvote by the way... I will try it and see

Comment: @Kenzo You can't do permanent style changes with `:hover`. You can have an onclick event faked via CSS or you can do mouse events via JS. If you're already using Angular and that router in your comment above, that is an important consideration to mention in your question, I think.

Comment: @Kenzo... see the edited answer to see the code in action.

Comment: @DudeCoder I am trying to figure out the Angular way of doing this. Will check

Comment: @TylerH the routerlink is adding an active class to my <li> tag, but the css is :before the <a> tag.  I've tried changing the active styling to :after but that does not work either.

Comment: @Kenzo.. I think that you should not waste your time in that... My code is working.. so whats wrong with that..

Comment: @Kenzo `:before` and `:after` are not talking about time, they are taking about location. They mean "before the element's starting edge" and "after the element's ending edge".

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with this.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:before {
 visibility: visible;
 -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
 transform: scaleX(1);
}
```